# How to Fix multiple navigation on page Up and Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

working on navigation which is multiple floors red and green when user scroll down the page navigation should be hidden and when user scroll up the page the green navigation section should appear without red section.

I tried to a fixed green section with on scroll jQuery but red section hides because of position.

```js
$(function (){
 var lastScrollTop = 50;
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      var st = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (st >= 181){
      // alert('down');
      $('.nav').addClass('down');
      $('.nav').removeClass('up');
    } else {
      // alert('up');
      $('.nav').removeClass('down');
      $('.nav').addClass('up');
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
  });
});
```

```css
body, html {
  maring: 0; padding: 0;
}

.top-header {
  height: 25px; background-color: red;
}
.nav {
  height: 75px; background-color: green;
}
.sec-1 {
  margin-top: 75px;
}
img {
    width:100%; display: block;
  }

.stiky {
  transition: .3s all;
}
.down {
  position: fixed; top: -75px; width: 100%; left: 0; right: 0;
}
.up {
  position: fixed; top: 0px; width: 100%; left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-header">
  
</div>
<header class="nav stiky">
  
</header>
<section class="sec-1">
  <div>
    <img src="https://data.whicdn.com/images/23540823/original.jpg" alt="img-1">
  </div>
</section>
```

For output, When user scrolls down >= 100 scrolls then both rad & green section disappears. when the user scrolls Up then the Green section appear without rad section after user reached out <= 100 scroll everything should be same as per below image. please find the image attachment.

[image]

Comment: Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we know what code you have?

Comment: I add code please check.